# Which AAD Application Type should I use?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, office-js, office-addins

I have an Outlook Office Add-In (OWA) which makes calls to a WEB-API which was written in house.  This Office Add-In will run on the Web, Windows Desktop Client, and on Mobile Devices.

When I register the App in AAD should I use 
**Native** because the Office Add-In is running on the Desktop, and Mobile
or
**Web app / API** because our Web Service (WebAPI) is running on a secure server?

Answer (score 1):

You should use **Web app / API** because it is the web app that needs to be authorized.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation!  I'm still new at this and wasn't sure.